# fatal: Invalid refspec (Heroku nodejs)

Tags: node.js, github, heroku

I am getting this error on running:

```
git push heroku master
fatal: Invalid refspec ' https://git.heroku.com/damp-reef-82414.git'


Heroku Git URL - https://git.heroku.com/lit-earth-17372.git
https://lit-earth-17372.herokuapp.com/
```

https://git.heroku.com/damp-reef-82414.git was directory earlier on heroku ,
current folder's link through herolu create command is  https://lit-earth-17372.herokuapp.com/

.git/config

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[remote "abc"]
    url = https://git.heroku.com/lit-earth-17372.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/abc/*
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Comment: Can you try to be clear on what your problem is, maybe you can provide the error message you're getting.

Comment: Are you trying to adjust your `heroku` remote so it points at `lit-earth-17372` instead of `damp-reef-82414`?

Comment: yes yes, I had 'damp-reef-82414' domain earlier , 'lit-earth-17372' is the current one @Chris

Comment: while pushing it on heroku I am facing this error. ' damp-reef-82414' was one of domain with some other project earlier, it has been deleted long time ago, lit-earth-17372 is the current one  @antzshrek

Comment: @Kapoor, have you tried VonC's suggestion? I think he may have the solution.

Comment: @Kapoor Can you add the same url to origin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see `' https://git.heroku.com/damp-reef-82414.git'` with a space at the beginning.

Just in case this is some kind of typo, try:

```
cd /path/to/my/local/repo
git remote set-url heroku https://git.heroku.com/damp-reef-82414.git
```

The same command can be used to switch to `https://git.heroku.com/lit-earth-17372.git` if needed.

Comment: same error: command : git remote set-url heroku https://git.heroku.com/lit-earth-17372.git  result : fatal: Invalid refspec ' https://git.heroku.com/damp-reef-82414.git'

Comment: @Kapoor I still see a space in there: could you edit it out with a `git config --edit` done within your repo?

Comment: in .git/config url is current on but it is still referring to some other link. I have uploaded the .git/config (with the Question above) can you please check.

Comment: @Kapoor I have. Can you add an url to origin, just in case that is an issue?